# Adding custom PHP code to BigCommerce store

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I want to add custom PHP code to my BigCommerce store. I know how to create panels and add them to pages however this only allows for HTML code. What I want to do with the code, only on specific pages ( confirmation/transaction complete ) is to generate a custom tracking pixel which needs to include the buyer's information, order information etc. Some of the information is gathered from a cookie placed elsewhere and the rest is order related.

How, preferably without needing to create an app, can I add PHP code to my store to specific pages to get order, cookie, client information and generate redirections and also custom tracking pixels.?

I know bigcommerce's PHP code is closed source, but is it at all possible to add PHP code of my own?

Comment: tried anything so far ?

Comment: Contacted support, they said only developers have access to the PHP part of the system and I should try stackoverflow for a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add your own PHP to your Bigcommerce store.
Write your code for the taking pixel in javascript.

Comment: Indeed you cannot add your own PHP code. Luckily the system I need to integrate has code for all scripting languages including JavaScript. Hopefully BigCommerce will have the globals I need to achieve my goal. Seems to be the only way I will be able to generate a dynamic pixel.

Comment: Variables with transaction data are exposed already on the FinishrdOrder.php order confirmation page. They are there for the Google Analytics and other tacking codes such as this. You should have what you need.